# element with tabindex 0 to next element with tabindex 1+ is not focused

Tags: html, tabindex

I am having a HTML template with set of `<a>` tags. Added tabindex for the elements.

Issue is on clicking tab button to focus, element with tabindex 1+ is not focusing.

Requirement is focus should happen on changing the focus from element with tabindex 0 to an element with tabindex 1+.

```
<div>
    <ul class="gn-filter-anchor-list">

        <li>
            <a title="Under $25.00" tabindex="0" href="/"><span class="off-screen">from Price</span> Under $25.00</a></li>
        <li>
            <a title="$25.00-$49.00" tabindex="0" href="/"><span class="off-screen">from Price</span> $25.00-$49.00</a></li>
        <li>
            <a title="$50.00-$74.00" tabindex="0" href="/"><span class="off-screen">from Price</span> $50.00-$74.00</a></li>
        <li>
            <a title="$75.00-$99.00" tabindex="0" href="/"><span class="off-screen">from Price</span> $75.00-$99.00</a></li>
        <li>
            <a title="Over $100.00" tabindex="0" href="/"><span class="off-screen">from Price</span> Over $100.00</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div >
    <div class="dept-large"><a href="/" tabindex="2">xxx</a></div>
    <div class="dept-large"><a href="/" tabindex="1">xxx</a></div>
    <div class="dept-large"><a href="/" tabindex="1">xxx</a></div>  
</div>
<div >
    <ul class="pagination" >
        <li class="current"><a href="#" >1</a></li>
        <li class="odd first"><a href="#" >2</a></li>
        <li class="even"><a href="#" >3</a></li>
        <li class="odd"><a href="#" >4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sameer_ngl/mjps7ufs/

Comment: Please make your question more clear, exact requirements, example of expected behavior perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

See below:

The tabindex global attribute is an integer indicating if the element can take input focus (is focusable), if it should participate to sequential keyboard navigation, and if so, at what position. It can take several values:

- a negative value means that the element should be focusable, but
  should not be reachable via sequential keyboard navigation;
- 0 means that the element should be focusable and reachable via
  sequential keyboard navigation, but its relative order is defined
  by the platform convention;
- a positive value means should be focusable and reachable via
  sequential keyboard navigation; its relative order is defined by
  the value of the attribute: the sequential follow the increasing
  number of the tabindex. If several elements share the same
  tabindex, their relative order follows their relative position in
  the document.

An element with a 0 value, an invalid value, or no tabindex value should be placed after elements with a positive tabindex in the sequential keyboard navigation order.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: Just found this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115953/where-do-tabindex-0-html-elements-end-up-in-the-tabbing-order